# In Ruby/Sinatra, how to halt with an ERB template and error message

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

In my Sinatra project, I'd like to be able to halt with both an error code and an error message:

```
halt 403, "Message!"
```

I want this, in turn, to be rendered in an error page template (using ERB). For example:

```
error 403 do
    erb :"errors/error", :locals => {:message => env['sinatra.error'].message}
end
```

However, apparently `env['sinatra.error'].message` (aka the readme and every single website says I should do it) does not expose the message I've provided. (This code, when run, returns the `` undefined method `message' for nil:NilClass `` error.)

I've searched for 4-5 hours and experimented with everything and I can't figure out where the message is exposed for me to render via ERB! Does anyone know where it is?

---

(It seems like the only alternative I can think of is writing this instead of the `halt` code above, every time I would like to halt:

```
halt 403, erb(:"errors/error", :locals => {m: "Message!"})
```

This code works. But this is a messy solution since it involves hardcoding the location of the error ERB file.)

(If you were wondering, this problem is not related to the `show_exceptions` configuration flag because both `set :show_exceptions, false` and `set :show_exceptions, :after_handler` make no difference.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why doesn't it work − use the source!

Lets look at the Sinatra source code to see why this problem doesn't work. The main Sinatra file ([`lib/sinatra/base.rb`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb)) is just 2043 lines long, and pretty readable code!

All `halt` does is:

```
def halt(*response)
  response = response.first if response.length == 1
  throw :halt, response
end
```

And exceptions are caught with:

```
# Dispatch a request with error handling.
def dispatch!
  invoke do
    static! if settings.static? && (request.get? || request.head?)
    filter! :before
    route!
  end
rescue ::Exception => boom
  invoke { handle_exception!(boom) }
  [..]
end

def handle_exception!(boom)
  @env['sinatra.error'] = boom
  [..]
end
```

But for some reason this code is never run (as tested with basic "printf-debugging"). This is because in `invoke` the block is run like:

```
# Run the block with 'throw :halt' support and apply result to the response.
def invoke
  res = catch(:halt) { yield } 
  res = [res] if Fixnum === res or String === res
  if Array === res and Fixnum === res.first
    res = res.dup
    status(res.shift)
    body(res.pop)
    headers(*res)
  elsif res.respond_to? :each
    body res
  end
  nil # avoid double setting the same response tuple twice
end
```

Notice the `catch(:halt)` here. The `if Array === res and Fixnum === res.first` part is what `halt` sets and how the response body and status code are set.

The `error 403 { .. }` block is run in `call!`:

```
invoke { error_block!(response.status) } unless @env['sinatra.error']
```

So now we understand *why* this doesn't work, we can look for solutions ;-)

### So can I use halt some way?

Not as far as I can see. If you look at the body of the `invoke` method, you'll see that the body is always set when using `halt`. You don't want this, since you want to *override* the response body.

### Solution

Use a "real" exception and not the `halt` "pseudo-exception". Sinatra doesn't seem to come with pre-defined exceptions, but the `handle_exception!` does look at `http_status` to set the correct HTTP status:

```
  if boom.respond_to? :http_status
    status(boom.http_status)
  elsif settings.use_code? and boom.respond_to? :code and boom.code.between? 400, 599
    status(boom.code)
  else
    status(500)
  end
```

So you could use something like this:

```
require 'sinatra'

class PermissionDenied < StandardError
    def http_status; 403 end
end

get '/error' do
    #halt 403, 'My special message to you!'
    raise PermissionDenied, 'My special message to you!'
end

error 403 do
    'Error message -> ' +  @env['sinatra.error'].message
end
```

Which works as expected (the output is `Error message -> My special message to you!`). You can return an ERB template here.

Answer (score 2):

In Sinatra v2.0.7+, messages passed to `halt` are stored in the body of the response. So a `halt` with an error code and an error message (eg: `halt 403, "Message!"`) can be caught and rendered in an error page template with:

```
error 403 do
  erb :"errors/error", locals: { message: body[0] }
end
```